# which end of a packet is up

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: [The DHCP Handbook, 2nd Edition by Ralph Droms and Ted Lemon (2003)](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_DHCP_Handbook.html?id=8acohIuwp6QC&redir_esc=y)

Example:

> Thanks to Cisco, Bucknell University, Vint Cerf and the Corporation for National Research Initiatives, Joe D’Andrea and my other friends at Quadritek Systems (now a part of Lucent Technologies), and Mike Carney of Sun Microsystems for supporting my activities as chair of the DHCWG and making it possible to write this book. Doug Comer first gave me an opportunity to learn **which end of a packet is up**.

I suppose this is some sort of joke or a pun on something. Any idea what exactly he is talking about?

Comment: Since the book is about networking, I believe it's a personal incident and so a personal message from the writer to Comer, a friend who helped him understand something about Packets. A Packet I believe can be a TCP Packet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"To not know which end is up" means "to be totally clueless and ignorant" about something; and a "packet" is one of the most basic concepts in various networking protocols; so the author is saying that he had been completely clueless about networking before Doug Comer first gave him the chance to learn about it (which was, presumably, many years ago).